# How does the ConventionModelMapper determine set/bag relationships

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I'm using mapping by code in a new application and seeing some odd behavior with the convention model mapper.  It's selecting all but one of my 1..N relationships as a Bag and one as a Set.  As far as I can see, they're all declared basically the same way.  More-over if I dont set up an event handler for BeforeMapSet, the appropriate BeforeMapManyToOne handler is never fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XML` mapping is more explicit in this way and usually maps *IList<>* to `<bag>` and *`ISet`* to `<set>`. There is an explanation, how the Fluent engine (from version 1.2) tries to do the same:

https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping

*(see section HasMany / one-to-many / Collection Types)*

An extract from the link above:

```
public IList<Child> Children { get; set; }    
HasMany(x => x.Children); // <bag />


private ISet<Child> _children;    
public IEnumerable<Child> Children
{
  get { return _children; }
}

HasMany(x => x.Children); // <set access="nosetter.camelcase-underscore" />


private ISet<Child> _children;    
public IEnumerable<Child> GetChildren()
{
  return _children;
}

HasMany(x => x.GetChildren()); // <set name="_children" access="field" />
```

So I would guess, that your "small differencies" in mapping could be hidden there